# SQL order of operation does not make sense with simple mathematical calculation

Tags: sql

I have a simple calculation to do in a stored procedure.  Depending on the order I put the variables I get a different result

If you copy/past this into SQL Query Analyzer you can easily reproduce the issue where I get a different result.  The result I was looking for was the second calculation (57364.32)

```
DECLARE @mnyDocTotal MONEY;
DECLARE @mnyUSDTotal MONEY
DECLARE @mnyDetailLine MONEY

SET @mnyDocTotal = 78000
SET @mnyUSDTotal = 86046.48
SET @mnyDetailLine = 52000

PRINT 'Result: ' + CAST(ROUND(@mnyDetailLine / @mnyDocTotal * @mnyUSDTotal,2) as char(20))
PRINT 'Result: ' + CAST(ROUND(@mnyDetailLine * @mnyUSDTotal / @mnyDocTotal,2) as char(20))

--Result:             57358.58
--Result:             57364.32
```

I believe that / and * are on the same level and operate from left to right in this case.

If you run the numbers with a calculator, you will always get 57364.32.

This caused me about 2 hours of effort to figure this out.  In all my years I've never had this issue occur.  Why is the result different?

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: That is not standard SQL.

Comment: The Impaler, I am using Microsoft Azure SQL Server database.

Comment: Acorn, I'd like to know what you mean by not standard SQL.  Can you give me a pointer or two on what I would do to make it standard?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/avoid-use-money-smallmoney-datatypes) does a pretty good job explaining why you should not use `money`.

They are not numeric values.  They are stored as integers.  And they have rounding problems.  So:

```
(a * b) / c
```

can product a different result due to rounding from:

```
(a / c) * b
```

This is actually true of integers in general, as this simple example illustrates:

```
select (2 * 4 / 3), (2 / 3 * 4)
```

If you use numeric, you won't have a problem.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d12ad0bb6d71369cd86e1ebb1a1e372d) is a db<>fiddle.